# What is the difference between two pieces of code, written on React, containing useEffect hook and some async stuff within it?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, react-testing-library, use-effect

I write a service to monitor information about stocks of different companies. I have a local server that serves as a "proxy" which makes data more convenient to process. I write a piece of code, which function is to fetch data about companies that user added to his profile (actually users do not have a possibility to create a profile in my service yet so I save data to `localStorage`) from my server just after component rendered first time. The first implementation:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { StockItem } from './StockItem';

export const StocksList = () => {
  const [ stocks, setStocks ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStocks = async () => {
      const userStocks = localStorage.getItem('userStocks');
      if (!userStocks) {
        return;
      }

      const userStocksList = JSON.parse(userStocks);
      const stockSymbolsParam = userStocksList.join(',');

      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stocks?stockSymbols=${stockSymbolsParam}`
      );
      const { data: stocksResponse, status } = response;
      if (status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Invalid request to API');
      }

      const { stocksData } = stocksResponse;
      let initialStocks = [];

      const processStockData = (stockData) => {
        const {
          symbol,
          data: {
            companyName,
            price,
            change,
          },
        } = stockData;

        const stock = {
          company: {
            name: companyName,
            symbol
          },
          price,
          change,
        };

        initialStocks.push(stock);
      };

      stocksData.forEach(item => processStockData(item));
      setStocks(prevState => [ ...prevState, ...initialStocks ]);
    };

    fetchStocks();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <ul data-testid='stocks-list'>
        {
          stocks.map(stock => {
            return (
              <StockItem key={stock.company.symbol} data={stock} />
            )
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </section>
  )
};
```

And when I using this one, all my tests pass. But when I decided to change 
 and split code for `fetchData` function reusability, something broke, although in my opinion both pieces do the same thing. The new one:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { StockItem } from './StockItem';

export const StocksList = () => {
  const [ stocks, setStocks ] = useState([]);

  const fetchStocks = async (symbols) => {
    const stockSymbolsParam = symbols.join(',');
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stocks?stockSymbols=${stockSymbolsParam}`
    );
    const { data: stocksResponse, status } = response;
    if (status !== 200) {
      throw new Error('Invalid request to API');
    }

    const { stocksData } = stocksResponse;
    let resultStocks = [];
    const processStockData = (stockData) => {
      const {
        symbol,
        data: {
          companyName,
          price,
          change,
        },
      } = stockData;

      const stock = {
        company: {
          name: companyName,
          symbol
        },
        price,
        change,
      };

      resultStocks.push(stock);
    };

    stocksData.forEach(item => processStockData(item));
    return resultStocks;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const userStocks = localStorage.getItem('userStocks');
    if (!userStocks) {
      return;
    }
    const userStocksList = JSON.parse(userStocks);

    (async () => {
      const result = await fetchStocks(userStocksList);
      setStocks(prevState => [ ...prevState, ...result ]);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <ul data-testid='stocks-list'>
        {
          stocks.map(stock => {
            return (
              <StockItem key={stock.company.symbol} data={stock} />
            )
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </section>
  )
};
```

Actually, the service still works, it fetches data and display stocks the SAME way it used to be, but the test which is testing `StocksList` component, fails. The test is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { StocksList } from './StocksList';
import fakeResponse from './fakeResponse';

jest.mock('axios');

it('should fetch stocks data about companies from localStorage after render', async () => {
    (axios.get as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce((url) => {
      const symbols = url.substr(url.indexOf('=') + 1).split(',');
      const response = fakeResponse(symbols);
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    });
    const fakeUserStocks = [ 'WIX', 'EBAY', 'AAPL' ];
    localStorage.setItem('userStocks', JSON.stringify(fakeUserStocks));

    const { getAllByTestId, rerender } = render(<StocksList />);
    localStorage.removeItem('userStocks');

    await expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    rerender(<StocksList />);
    const stockItems = getAllByTestId('stock-item');
    fakeUserStocks.forEach((userStock, i) => {
      expect(stockItems[i].innerHTML.indexOf(userStock)).not.toEqual(-1);
    });
  });
```

The message, test is failing with, is:

```
✕ should fetch stocks data about companies from localStorage after render (30ms)

  ● StocksList testing › should fetch stocks data about companies from localStorage after render

    Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="stock-item"]

    <body>
      <div>
        <section
          class="stocksSection"
        >
          <ul
            class="stocksList"
            data-testid="stocks-list"
          />
        </section>
      </div>
    </body>

      35 |
      36 |     rerender(<StocksList />);
    > 37 |     const stockItems = getAllByTestId('stock-item');
         |                        ^
      38 |     fakeUserStocks.forEach((userStock, i) => {
      39 |       expect(stockItems[i].innerHTML.indexOf(userStock)).not.toEqual(-1);
      40 |     });
```

And I want to figure out, is there a problem with my code (e.g. something tricky, connected with `Hooks API` etc), with my test or, if neither of them, with some other stuff which are in source code, but removed to not to clutter the issue (for instance, `Typescript` typings, but I remind that everything works except the test)? Every help is pretty welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your test and why is it failing ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel add both test and message it is failing with.

Comment: the problem with both these pieces is that after first render callback, passed to useEffect, is called. And since the callback is async, while the test is sync, test goes on, while there's no response returned and, as a result, no StockItems rendered when I try to get them in test. The way out is to replace getAllByTestId, which is sync, with findAllByTestId, which is async and so it is executed after response is returned and so there are all the StockItems rendered. However, I still don't know what is the reason of such a weird behaviour of all the code I provided.

Comment: it should be `await findAllByTestId` instead of `getAllByTestId`.